# How to reference the array push is being called upon?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to create an array, where the first element and the last element are the same.  I would like to be able to do so without having to assign the array a name. Consider the following code:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].push(self[0])
```

Obviously, this use of `self` is in error because `self` refers to the main object.  And so, my question:

*When I call `.push`, in its parameters how do I refer to the array push is being called upon?*

Comment: Any word about the motivation? Why does it have to be anonymous (without a name). Why does it need to have the first and last element the same? Who consumes the list and how? :)

Comment: Good question.  It's for a programming challenge, I would probably never do this in real life.  I'm just daisy-chaining a bunch of list operations.

Comment: I'm evaluating a list 2 elements at a time (with `.each_cons(2)`) and I need to pretend like the array is circular. (Similar to the concept of circular linked lists (which if I'm not mistaken ruby doesn't have, but correct me if I'm wrong))  I'm trying to get my iterator to evaluate two elements at a time, but evaluate the first element and the last element together as if they were consecutive.

Comment: You can use `cycle` (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) for treating e.g. a list as a ring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, one option is to use [instance_eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) to make `self` refer to the object you are working with:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].instance_eval { self.push(self[0]) }
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this *without* changing the context of `self` is to use [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap) - which will yield the object to a block, and then return the (new) value of the object:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].tap { |a| a << a[0] }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]

# Or equivalently:
[1, 2, 3, 4].tap { |a| a.push(a[0]) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (which *generally* would not be recommended, especially in a large project, as it pollutes the core classes; but could be a viable choice in a small script) would be to define a method in the `Array` class itself:

```
class Array
  def push_first
    push(first)
  end  
end  

[1, 2, 3, 4].push_first
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```